# problem in using FileField and validate in flask with together

Tags: python, validation, flask, flask-wtforms

I am using wtforms for creating form and vaidation. it is somthing like this:

```
class Test(FlaskForm):

image = FileField('تصویر', validators=[
    FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'], 'only image.')
])

year = IntegerField('سال', validators=[DataRequired(), year_check(max=15)])

month = IntegerField('سال', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(1,31)])

day = IntegerField('روز', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(1,31)])

def validate(self):
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  
        if not FlaskForm.validate(self):
            return False

        if self.year.data and  self.month.data and self.day.data: 
            try:
                d = JalaliDate(int(self.year.data), int(self.month.data) , int(self.day.data))
            except:
                self.day.errors.append('تاریخ اشتباه می باشد')
                return False
        return True
```

Validation function give day, month and year in [jalali date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_calendars) and if they aren't valiead make an validationerror.

And html form is like :

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="Post">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

        <div class="custom-file">
            {{ form.image.label (class_="custom-file-label") }}
            {{ form.image(class_="custom-file-input") }}
        </div>
```

in the view i get filefield like this:

```
file = request.files['image']
```

and save them in database.
when submit the form this error is showed:

```
Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

when i delete the on of the FileField or validation function it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is this part of code:

```
file = request.files['image']
```

when error occurred when any file chooses for upload. then i changed the code:

```
if 'image' in request.files:
    file = request.files['image']
```

I fined it from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/8b8l7l/best_way_to_handle_file_uploads/)